# combining the impact of absolute value and YoY change

Tags: analytics, metrics

I am currently working on a problem where we are ranking a customer demographic by absolute value of sales or by the YoY (year-over-year) change in sales.

As is obvious, looking at both these metrics at the same time lets us know whether the growth we are witnessing is actually substantial or not.

For example, let's say a state had a YoY growth of 200% by the end of 2021, but if the absolute value of sales only changed from $100 to $300, it is not actual growth with regards to the hundred thousand dollar values we usually see for other states.

I am looking for ways to **combine the effect of both these metrics** (absolute value and YoY change) and **create a composite metric** which can be used to rank my customer demographic.

Answer (score 0):

A common way to combine two metrics is to normalise them to the same range, e.g. 0..1 and then take a weighted average. However there's always a question as to what the weights should be, and, more importantly, what such a metric means. From my experience, I'd advise against trying to combine metrics this way.